# Can I tell which template instance class(es) my class is inheriting from?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, reflection, multiple-inheritance

Given this code:

```
template < int I >
class Foo
{
public:
    int v;
    Foo() { v = I; }
    virtual ~Foo() {}
};

class Bar : public Foo<0>, public Foo<3>
{
public:
    template < int I >
    int getValue() { return Foo<I>::v; }
};

int main() {
    Bar b;
    cout << b.getValue<0>() << endl; // prints 0
    cout << b.getValue<3>() << endl; // prints 3
    cout << b.getValue<4>() << endl; // compiler error
    return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to iterate over all `Foo<i>` classes from which `Bar` inherits? We can assume that `i` is between 0 and some maximum `N`. In pseudocode:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
{
    if ( Bar inherits from `Foo<i>` )
    {
        cout << Foo<i>::v << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have an upper bound on `i`, then you can write a recursive function template that calls `boost::is_base_of<YourClass, Foo<i> >` for each `i` value between 0 and your upper bound.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go ([live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/70140bae951bce58)):

```
struct _do { template <typename... A> _do(A&&...) { } };

template <int... I>
class Bar_impl : public Foo<I>...
{
public:
    template < int K >
    int getValue() { return Foo<K>::v; }

    template <typename F>
    void loop(F&& f) { _do{(std::forward<F>(f)(getValue<I>()), 0)...}; }
};

using Bar = Bar_impl<0,3>;
```

Now `Bar` implementation holds all indices of base classes in variadic parameter `I...` and derives all base classes `Foo<I>...` in a variadic fashion.

Function `loop` iterates over all bases using the auxiliary `struct` `_do`. You can pass an arbitrary function, lambda or function object `f` to `loop`. Then `f` will be called on `getValue<I>()` for all `I...`, i.e., on member `v` of every base class.

You use this as follows:

```
void print(int i) { cout << i << " "; }

int main() {
    Bar b;
    b.loop(print); // prints 0 3
    cout << endl;
}
```

In other words, you don't need to *detect* if an object is an instance of some class. You make the object *know* its own bases by construction.

Now you may realize that if you make `Foo` a template on the member type (instead of `int`), you are quite close to start building your own [very basic tuple](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/44832/39083).

Comment: Cheers. Unfortunately, I may not have access to C++11 features in my project. Is something like this still feasible in pre-11 C++ ?

Comment: Yes, but not that conveniently. You have to use recursion, both for the definition of `Bar` and for function `loop`. [Here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/44546/39083) was a recursive tuple definition that I made into non-recursive. You can use the same pattern for `Bar`. I guess `loop` will be much easier. The idea of knowing instead of detecting remains the same.

Comment: @suszterpatt Because there are no variadic templates here, you'll have to build `Bar<0,3,5>` with a structure like `node<0,node<3,node<5> > >`, inheriting both `Foo<0>` and `node<3,node<5> >` etc., if you know what I mean.